# python Force git hook server side output on same line in realtime

Tags: python, git, githooks

git hooks server side output only transmits on a newline. I want to configure a custom task and print real-time output on the same line. How can I achieve that? I tried sys.stdout.flush but it transmits everything once complete. It does work in real-time if I add a newline. 
I want something like

> Step A)Started......Completed

with each '.' appended after a given time.

My current code looks like the following and it outputs only when the method is completed.

```
import sys, time, os


def print_realtime():
    sys.stdout.write('Started.')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(1, 15):
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_realtime()
```

However, it works in realtime if I append '\n' like:

```
sys.stdout.write('.\n')
```

Comment: Welcome at Stackoverflow. Unfortunately I can't comprehend the nature of the problem. Please have a look at the SO guide on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you follow this guideline you will be much more likely getting useful answers.

Comment: Hi @MrLeeh  I updated the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: That's still not a [mcve]. An MCVE would be a *complete Python program* that one could set up as a Git hook to demonstrate the problem. (Probably you should strip out all the ProcessPoolExecutor and logging code and just have a function that writes to stdout, unless that makes the problem go away, in which case you have a new clue.)

Comment: I added a python program which could be setup as git hook. If I execute the program directly it works fine appending '.' in real-time but when I set it up as pre-receive hook it just waits and prints everything at the end. Not sure what has to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes down to the fact that Git itself does not print accumulated `remote:` text until the remote sends [either a newline or carriage return](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1eb437020a2c098a7c12da4c05082fbea10d98c9/sideband.c#L67).

Hence, if we change your inner loop to read:

```
for i in range(1, 15):
    sys.stdout.write('.' * i + '\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

you will see the effect you desire.

Note that the `\r` moves the print position back to just after the word `remote:`, so we must repeat what we have printed so far (hence the need to print first one `.`, then two `.`s, then three, and so on).