# Output realtime in git post-receive script

Tags: git, githooks

I have some **remote repositories** (started with **--bare**) on a Linux Ubuntu machine (14.04 and 16.04). These repositories receive commits and from there the events of the **hooks** scripts begin deploying the applications. The script used by deploy is the **post-receive**.

I would, however, like this script to show the **output to the client pushing the commit in real time** and not just when the script is finished.

According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144606/5560913) and [this line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1eb437020a2c098a7c12da4c05082fbea10d98c9/sideband.c#L67), the buffer is apparently unloaded whenever a new line is written to the output by the script.

But I've tried this in several ways and none worked. I only get the response on the client that is pushing the commit when the script ends.

I've already tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "A - Starting deploy. \n";
echo "A - Starting deploy. \n\r";
echo "A - Starting deploy. \r";
echo -e "A - Starting deploy. \n";
echo -e "A - Starting deploy. \n\r";
echo -e "A - Starting deploy. \r";
printf "A - Starting deploy. \n";
printf "A - Starting deploy. \n\r";
printf "A - Starting deploy. \r";

# Code for deploy ...

echo "B - Finished deploy.";
```

But all outputs, both "A" and "B" started, **only appear** on the client console when the entire **script ends**.

I would like each line to be presented to the client as the script executes.

I believe this is possible because I use the lib [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to upload AWS S3 assets, and while it uploads, the outputs are shown in the execution, not just at the end, as shown below. It is also interesting that the outputs I wrote are sent in the response also when s3cmd starts sending its outputs.

[image: realtime outputs]

Can someone help me?

Comment: it sounds like a [buffering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5140923/2303202). Does it do it same way if you push from commandline? Try to prepend the echo commands with the stdbuf utility as described in the link.